# Prevent REST clients of simultaneous executing same methods with same arguments

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

Consider `Spring MVC` java web-application, which provides some `REST API`.

Let's say it has many methods, one of them is `DELETE /api/foo/{id}`, which obviously deletes `foo` entity from the DB with given `id`.

The problem is that due to big data in the DB, this operation is not immediate, so if client tries perform simultaneously multiply delete operations on same entity, say

`DELETE /api/foo/123` x N times (by mistake in client software of course),

it causes some unpleasant side effects in the DB (you know, if you try delete same entity in several transactions, that's not generally nice).

My question is: what is the best practice in `Spring MVC` to prevent such situations?

I can certainly introduce synchronisation on `Foo` id in each such update method (`PUT/DELETE`). I will need to do it for all entities and all `PUT/DELETE` API methods though, which I really don't want to do. I suppose it should be some elegant and nice solution, how to perform such type of synchronisation on interceptor/servlet level, i.e. not on service of controller level.

I can also create specific interceptor and perform there waiting for duplicated requests (requests with same URL and parameters). But again, it doesn't sound as an elegant solution (until I will be ensured that it is not possible to configure in `Spring MVC` somehow in more beauty way).

Comment: In principle, the transaction mechanism is designed for this purpose. What further requirements you have that you consider transaction rollback as  **unpleasant side effects in the DB** ?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that different DBs have different behaviour for such kind of events. In my case I got some kind of blocking because of complex replication structure. I generally don't want to catch and receive any kind of such exceptions from the DB, I want to prevent their appearance.

Comment: I am right or wrong. I don't know as per my knowledge we can do one thing just check the data is available in db or not like getFooById(id); if you get the data than you can delete same data otherwise you can throw the exception that data is not there

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem of concurrency that shall be handled by using the appropriate transaction and locking level. Unfortunately, there is no single size fits all way here and depending on your actual requirements, you could have to implement optimistic or pessimistic locking, as well as one of the possible transaction level (from no transaction at all to serializable transactions).

In general, handling such questions at the web level is a bad idea, because you will end in questions like what to do in on request wants to delete some data that another one is displaying at the same time? In SpringMVC, the common way is to use transactional methods in the service layer. Additionaly, you should declare an optimistic or pessimistic locking system in the persistence layer.

Optimistic layer normally give a higher throughput, at the cost of some transaction ending in exceptions. In that case, current best practices are now to report the problem to the user asking him/her to send his/her request again.

Comment: The problem that this approach doesn't cover my current hassles. Several multiple requests of DELETE of same raw in heavy loaded DB causes kind of blocking, so all this multiple requests fail with 504 timeout error. Certainly all delete methods themself  are performed in transactional level. But it doesn't cover case when DB itself behaves in improper way.

Comment: 504 timeout error on delete requests is generaly a symptom of not being able to get a (pessimistic) lock. But this a the hard part of optimizing the database accesses and it heavily depends on the database itself and the major use cases. I'm sorry, but I am afraid I cannot say much more. Maybe you could try to replace pessimistic locks with optimistic ones to exchange 504 timeout errors with messages like *System was busy and could not complete your request, please try again..*

Comment: That's not suitable. As I wrote in my question, the direct way will be introduce synchronisation on particular entities's ids. This will simply prevent DB from being locked, so it will be no any hassles with timeout exceptions - sequentially executed DELETE methods will quickly return OK, as deleting of an absent entity in my API is legal operation. My question was about: is it possible or not, use existent capabilities of Spring MVC framework to do the same trick on more higher level.

Comment: @Andremoniy: I'm not aware of anything apart from transaction at Spring level. And at the Web level, nothing better that an interceptor...